# Did Goddess Manasa live in Bengal?

Tags: goddess

I have heard that Goddess Manasa lived in Bengal. Is this true or false?

Comment: Gods don't live on earth.Earth is for we humans.Gods have their respective Lokas where they reside. :).In short Devas reside in Deva Loka,Asuras in Patal Loka and Humans in Martya Loka (i.e earth).

Comment: @Rickross,but why Lord Shiva lived in Earth?

Comment: You mean Mount Kailas?Actually God's plane of existence is quite different from our concept of planes.They actually don't literally live on earth.Martya loka is for only those beings to live upon who have "mrityu" or death & Gods don't have it.Lord Shiva actually resides in Shiva Loka & it would not be entirely correct to say that that loka is on the earth itself. ;)

Comment: @Rickross,your answer is not true because everyone knows that Lord Shiva live in Mt.Kailash which is in China!!!

Comment: @Rickross,why Lord Rama,Lord Krishna and Hanuman were lived in Ayodhya,Vrindavan and Mathura? Now answer!!!

Comment: All of them are incarnations of Gods.And they were born on earth from human yonis.So,they are bound to live on earth.:)But is Goddess Manasa a human incarnation born of a human yoni?Don't think so.

Comment: You should ask some chinese people then if they know about someone called Lord Shiva living in their country.:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Goddess Manasa(মনসা) lives in bengal! because she is a goddess.God or Goddess don't live in earth. you might know goddess Manasa has 12 major names, one of them is Vaishnavi. though Surasa is the name of kashyap muni's wife one of the dahsha putriee. Goddess Manasa is also called Surasa. such like Padmavati is the name of goddess Lakshmi, but Goddess Manasa is also called Padma or Padmavati too. Manasa devi is a form of Shakti.as mata saraswati is power of knowledge, mata Lakshmi is power of wealth, mata parvati is power of stamina or kriya shakti. same to same Mata Manasa devi is the power of will that means ishsha shakti or chinta shakti. In Adya strotram it is said that,  adi parashakti lives in nether world in the form of vaishnavi.and she lives in manidweepam in the form of Surasa.  so it is clear that Mata Manasa devi maybe  lives in manidweepam or she lives in nether world ( patal lok). By the way, goddess Manasa is not a just bengali devi! She is also worshiped entire Indian subcontinent in many forms,,,,, such south Indian people worship her by the names Karumariamman( Not Mariamman), Nagathamman,Nagamma, Nageswari amman etc.
so i think You got your answer my friend  :-)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Goddess Manasa lived in Bengal. That's why she is mainly worshiped in the Bengal region. Behula and Lakshmichandra also lived in the Bengal region and that's why Manasa could disturb them. Manasa's actual name is 'Monosha' which is a Bengali name. Believe my answer and this is truth!

Comment: You mean if Goddess Manasa lived on some other planet or in some other parts of India(other than bengal) then she could not have disturbed Behula & Lakshindar ? :)

Comment: @Rickross,are you sure that your answer is true?

Comment: I don't know exactly if what you are saying is true or not.Incarnations of Gods as humans can only live on earth,Gods don't live on earth so to speak.Anyways,you should try to post citations for your answer as well.:)